# API or Service to fetch metadata of table in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to find an API or service to fetch the metadata of tables in Azure SQL database.  However, I can't find anything.  I only have an API that gets metadata of a database.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and give some more background on what you're looking for?

Comment: Hello! Just to give a context, we currently have on-premise MS SQL database.  Using DELL Boomi, we load the metadata of database's table/column/view in Collibra.

Right now, we are planning to migrate our on-premise database to Azure SQL database. But we are assessing the tools we might need to use to retain the our current requirement (stated above) even though SQL will be in Azure SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are no Azure ARM APIs for reading and writing from a database.

To read the metadata you must connect to the database with a SQL Server client and issue metadata queries, like

```
select *
from sys.tables
```

etc.  You can easily do this with PowerShell, SQLCMD, or [mssql-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/mssql-cli?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Hi David! Thanks for the feedback but are you saying that aside from querying it in the database there is no other way to get the metadata of tables/views of Azure SQL database?  Aside from querying is there an Azure service we can use instead? Thanks

Comment: Correct.  The Azure APIs are for administration of the database _itself_ not the tables, view, procedures, and data _inside_ the database.  The Azure API is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/